# Jenkins configure jobs to throw parameter

Tags: bash, jenkins, environment-variables

I have got three jobs.

1. (on Master) will prepare environment and start VM,
2. (on VM) have to catch the name of started VM and run tests,
3. (on Master) will revert to snapshot and shut down the VM.

How can i throw the variable wit VM name. My scripts is on bash

Comment: How is the job running on VM? Is there a Jenkins Slave that gets installed on the VM? Or are you just executing some remote code on VM directly, not through slave?

Comment: I will have got a slave in mysql database which on master, and when the  second job trigger the first one, it should run VM, book it in mysql and throw it's name to the second job on which it should be executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin)**.

On master, I assume the job that starts the VM knows the VM name.
On the same master job, setup a build step, post-build step, or automatic promotion (my preferred way) to **Call/Trigger Parameterized Build** (will be available after you install that plugin). 
In configuration for that step, you have an option to pass any number of parameters to the called job.

As for #3, since your job on the VM now has the VM name parameter, it can then further pass it to your third job (to revert snapshot and shut down) using the same plugin.

Comment: Now i have got a very block issue, my second job have to trigger prepare environment job and get VM name to run on it, but how it can be executed if it doesn't know the name on which it should execute? or this plugin can trigger without starting job and wait until get the VM name

Comment: You are contradicting yourself now. At first, you said that "first job will prepare environment and start VM". Now you are saying "my second job have to trigger prepare environment job". So which one is it?

Comment: maybe i'am incorrect, the second job have to trigger the job which will prepare environment and than it have to be executed on node which will get from the first job. is it possible&

Comment: Yes, you can pass whatever parameter you want from one job to another using that plugin

Comment: Slav, but how the second job will trigger the first which will create VM if it have to be run on smth node? or it can smth sent a trigger in offline mode? if yes, please provide